# Flutter || make elements inside a border

Tags: android, flutter, dart, border

In my flutter project I want to make the images and the text "See all" inside a border and I don't know how. I don't want a border for the hall page I want it just for the elements

This is my page :

[image]

This is my code :

```
Container(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            const SizedBox(height: 30),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: [              
                                        child: Text("Voir tous",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Color(0xff135888),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03,
                                          ),),
                                      SizedBox(
                                          width : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 3,
                                          child: Divider(
                                          color: Color(0xffD1D1D1),
                                          height: 10,
                                          thickness: 1,
                                          indent: 2,
                                          endIndent: 2,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),//Padding
                              Expanded(
                              child: GridView.count(
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                                shrinkWrap: false,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                children: [
                                  makeDashboardItem(
                                      "smart devices", "images/smarts.png", 0),
                                  makeDashboardItem(
                                      "Surveillance", "images/cameras.png", 1),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),//Expanded
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your **Divider**/**SizedBox** in a `Theme` widget.
It usually works with the **ExpansionTile**.

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData().copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
  child: // ...
)
```

Comment: It didn't work. Nothing shows